# Read MySQL table, encrypt it with pgp and write it as CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, pgp

I need to read some small MySQL tables, encrypt them with pgp using a password and write them as csv files. Is it possible to do that by using only SQL or Python or is Pandas needed?

Comment: Pandas is a Python library so you answered your own question.

Comment: I meant standard python not a framework like Pandas or Pyspark.